What kind of connector is this on my eval board?

What kind of connector is this?  This is on an eval kit and there is no resource anywhere that tells me what it is.

What kind of evaluation board is this? i.e. type, model, chip, manufacturer, etc.

Looks related to SCSI SCA connector, but shorter. Calling @DavideAndrea!

@winny A SCSI SCA is 80-pin, whereas this connector has two 50-pin "segments". From the picture it look like a single plastic housing is used for both of the two 50-pin "segments", rather than two 50-pin sockets placed end-to-end on the PCB. I had a quick search on https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN but didn't identify the connector.

@lemon this is a Sony IMX421 CMOS sensor evaluation kit.

@CNfan Can you add a link to a specific Sony IMX421 CMOS sensor evaluation kit, as on a search several manufacturers seem to supply evaluation kits based upon the  Sony IMX421 CMOS sensor. The FRAMOS SONY IMX421LLJ EVB-KIT SLVS-EC might be a match based upon the picture on that site, but there are no downloads shown on that web page. You might have to contact the manufacturer for support.

How about this one? https://www.amphenol-cs.com/product-series/phenphec-board-to-board.html Can you measure some dimensions and pitch of the connector?

@ChesterGillon yes I believe that is the one.  Framos is the manufacturer.  Technically can connect over SLVS-EC and SLVS, I am using the SLVS set up (goes through that connector).

My Identiconn identifies it as a Mini-D ribbon connector, a.k.a. Mini Delta Ribbon (MRD).

MANUF. - SERIES
KEL - 87 series (pdf)
DDK - DFM (pdf)
DDK - DHB (pdf)
Molex - EBBI 50D - digikey
Hirose Electric - EX (pdf) - digikey
Hirose Electric - FX2 (pdf) - digikey
Amphenol ICC - PHEC (pdf) - digikey


excellent tool name, by the way!

Maybe similar to the 3565 (and the like) from 3M?  We used to use piles of those.

"Maybe similar to the 3565 (and the like) from 3M?" 3M makes the  MRD 101 102

@DavideAndrea thanks for trying, however looking up Mini-D ribbon connectors I don't think its one of them.

I have rummaged through the BOM I made for a board I designed up to connect to it, and the mating partner connector is listed as a:
Board to Board & Mezzanine Connector
100P,1.27mm Pitch, Right Angle, SMT,Pl
NDP100-003-BF1 from Yamaichi Electronics.
So what the inverse of this is (on the dev kit) I still want to know (relevant to another question I have posted to stackexchange, where I realised I only put down "connector type X"...
Sony IMX421 Eval board with IMX422 Sensor - produces odd repeating patterns instead of true images

https://yeu.com/product/3001-2/

Is this an answer, or should it be an edit to the original post? Also, since the BOM was a board you designed, how did you choose mating parts?  (And how well did they mate, was it apparently exact, or with some error?)
